# Change form field options dynamically (and restore previously selected options) using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm fairly new to both jQuery and JavaScript so can anyone please point out what I'm missing here?

I have a form with multiple pairs of select fields, where the content of the second field relies on the selection of the first one.
Once a value is chosen from the first one then a piece of jQuery code empties the corresponding second select options, gets new values as JSON and inserts them as new select values. All of this works with the code I've written.

However if a user has chosen a second value, I'd like to restore it if possible (meaning if the new values also include the one previously selected).

I tried to do this by first saving the second value and then trying to set it once the new options have been inserted. This did not work. However when trying to debug I inserted an alert() just before restoring the second value and with that in there it does work...

Am I missing something very basic here? Any help would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<select name="party-0-first" id="id_party-0-first">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="1">first_value1</option>
<option value="2">first_value2</option>
<option value="3">first_value3</option>
<option value="4">first_value4</option>
</select>

<select name="party-0-second" id="id_party-0-second">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="1">second_value1</option>
<option value="2">second_value2</option>
<option value="3">second_value3</option>
<option value="4">second_value4</option>
</select>

<select name="party-1-first" id="id_party-1-first">
...
```

JavaScript:

```
$.fn.setSecond = function() {
    var divName = $(this).attr("name");
    divName = divName.replace('-first', '');
    divName = divName.replace('party-', '');

    // Save the currently selected value of the "second" select box
    // This seems to work properly
    setValue = $('#id_party-' + divName + '-second').val();

    // Get the new values
    $.getJSON("/json_opsys/", { client: $(this).val() },
    function(data){
        $('#id_party-' + divName + '-second').empty();
        $('#id_party-' + divName + '-second').append('<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>');
        $.each(data, function(i, item){
            $('#id_party-' + divName + '-second').append('<option value="' + item.pk + '">' + item.fields.name + '</option>');
        });
    });

    // Here I try to restore the selected value
    // This does not work normally, however if I place a javascript alert() before
    // this for some reason it does work
    $('#id_party-' + divName + '-second').val(setValue);


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[id*=first]').change(function() {
        $(this).setSecond();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, it looks like your `getJSON()` call is involved in that issue.

Remember, from the start, all ajax request are ASYNC, means your last line of code
there is most likely executed before the `getJSON()` success eventhandler is called.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the variable "setValue", try declaring it with `var`:

```
var setValue = $('#id_party-' + divName + '-second').val();
```

But I don't think that's the problem. The problem is that you're trying to reset the value in some code that's going to run *before* the getJSON is actually done. Try moving the thing that sets the value inside the function that's passed to getJSON.

```
$.getJSON("/json_opsys/", { client: $(this).val() },
function(data){
    $('#id_party-' + divName + '-second').empty();
    $('#id_party-' + divName + '-second').append('<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>');
    $.each(data, function(i, item){
        $('#id_party-' + divName + '-second').append('<option value="' + item.pk + '">' + item.fields.name + '</option>');
    });
    $('#id_party-' + divName + '-second').val(setValue);
});
```

Comment: That seems to have been the problem indeed! It's working great now! Thanks a lot!